# Empty character in properties file

Tags: java, properties

In my properties file I want to make this:

```
msg.error=Must introduce a\u0020
msg.error1=\u0020Must introduce
```

The problem is that this not work.

If I make:

```
msg.error=Must\u0020introduce
```

This works.

How can I introduce a empty character in beggining and end?